# why does the *built-in* python module 'sys' need to be explicitly imported with an 'import' statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules) says:

"One particular module deserves some attention: sys, which is built into every Python interpreter."

My understanding is that if a module is built into the Python interpreter itself, then there is no need for an explicit import statement. If the sys module is built-in the Python interpreter, then why is an explicit import statement required for the sys module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys` is imported at Python startup.  So when you import `sys`, it does not actually do anything except bind a variable name to the already-existing module.

When creating a module instance, there is no reason to have the `sys` name bound in the module scope when many (probably most) modules don't need to use `sys`.  So, that name is not in scope by default.

Comment: I understand now, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`import` performs two functions:

1. It loads the module from disk, initializing and executing it.
2. It adds the module to the local namespace.

With "built-in" modules item 1 is not an issue, but item 2 is still important; without it the code would throw a `NameError`.